# Populate a Select box in HTML using AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax, html, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a simple html5 page, that when the page loads, a Select HTML5 object will be populated with a list of values that are stored in an XML and called using an external javascript file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="javascript:loadXML()">
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
            <select id="cbLDAP"></select>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// variables declaration
var XML_PATH = "XML/ou.xml";
var select = $('#cdLDAP');
// load XML file
function loadXML()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XML_PATH,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml)
            {
                $(xml).find('LDAP').each(function()
                {
                    var ou = $(this).find('OU').text();
                    select.append("<option/><option class='ddheader'>"+ou+"</option>");
                });
                $(this).find('Name').each(function(){
                    var name = $(this).text();
                    select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ name +"'>"+name+"</option>");
                });
            }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DropDown>
    <LDAP>
        <OU>1</OU>
        <OU>2</OU>
        <OU>3</OU>
        <OU>4</OU>
        <OU>5</OU>
        <OU>6</OU>
    </LDAP>
</DropDown>
```

When I load my html file in Firefox 11, the Select object is not populated. What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo between the SELECT element's ID and the jQuery appending code. Also, you were iterating through the parent node that had not text values, as opposed to the child "OU" nodes.

Here's some example code that fixes the XML parsing and cleans up some incorrectly named element IDs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <h1></h1>
  </header>
  <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
      <select id="cdLDAP">
        <option/>
      </select>
  </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // variables declaration
    var XML_PATH = "XML/ou.xml";   
    // load XML file
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          $(xml).find('LDAP').find('OU').each(function(i) {
            var ou = $(this).text();
            $('#cdLDAP').append("<option class='ddheader'>"+ou+"</option>");
          });
          $(this).find('Name').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).text();
            $('#cdLDAP').append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ name +"'>"+name+"</option>");
          });
        }
      });
    });    
  </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Lastly, its worth noting that the onLoad action and wrapping the parsing code in a function isn't really necessary with jQuery; and don't forget to place the client-side code on the same server as the XML file, otherwise you will run into the same-origin policy blocking the AJAX fetch of the XML data.

Comment: what is that <script>... inside the <head> section?  Also,  Why did you pull out the javascript from a separate file and place it in the html file?  My understanding of best practices is to have all CSS files in one location, and js files in another, and so on.  Is this a bad practice?

Comment: In the <head> section I've added jQuery just as you had, only I've loaded the latest version of it, from the jQuery CDN. It is usually more efficient to load static files from a CDN, but in fact I just did that and made the script inline to make this a self-contained, easily runnable prototype. Inline scripts are useful for rapid development but I wouldn't suggest using them in a final product, although there may be some use-cases to do so, its usually more efficient to load all client-side code from a single JS file (or just a few) to reduce HTTP GET requests required on page load.

Comment: thanks this does work.  You are getting the check for sure, but I still have two questions. 1) What is the information inbetween the script tag un the "head" section for? 2) To use an external file, do I just change the second <scrip> tag to read `code<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: 1.) I'm not sure which characters or information in between the script tag and head you don't understand. If you mean the "charset"                                                                attribute, its an optional attribute to specify the encoding of the script file..............                                                     2.) Correct, you'd just copy and paste everything within the inline script, starting at text:  "// variables declaration"  and ending with the final closing brackets:  "});". Then put that in your "main.js" file and include the script as you described.

Comment: That's just the path (URL) to the JavaScript source file. In this case, its the full path to jQuery library loaded via its own Content Delivery Network (CDN) which is one of the recommended ways to load jQuery.